# Database connection doesn't work after redirect htaccess www

Tags: mysql, database, .htaccess, redirect, web

I am having a strange problem, when i access my site through mysite.org, everything loads fine, when I redirect mysite.org to mysite.org with www using htaccess I get the error saying that the database connection cannot be established.

I connect to the database this way:

```
require_once("conectar_a_base_de_dados.php")
```

Comment: Try `require_once(__DIR__."/conectar_a_base_de_dados.php")`

Comment: nope, it worked, i cleared the cache...